# Java web start dos and don'ts?

Tags: java, java-web-start

We are considering using java web start as our client server strategy. What is your experience with this technique? What do you like and dislike about it?

Comment: Java web start as Client Server strategy? It is more of a deployment technology as the name suggests Java Network Launch Protocol (JNLP).

Comment: @Faisai: WebStart also runs inside a security sandbox, and includes libraries to do operations outside that sandbox: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried Java Web Start as the deployment mechanism for my package. I had considerable difficulty getting it to work poorly. After about two weeks of effort, I abandoned it in favor of `install4j`, with which I've been happy.

Comment: Why did you start looking at it and what made you discard it?

Comment: I looked at it because it, ostensibly, did what I wanted and was free. Unfortunately, in order to detail why I abandoned it I would have to recapitulate my attempt at using it, which I don't want to do (sorry). I do recall two things that I couldn't get working: 1) installing Java 7 if necessary; and 2) associating a file-extension and mime-type with the application.

Answer (score 0):

My experience on JWS is not very extensive so far, but  I could note that if your software depends on libraries that are platform dependent and/or have thoughts of dynamically passing arguments to the application, it might not be as straight forward as one would hope. (that's the situation I'm in at least)

If I were in your shoes I would really take my time and weigh the options, read into the strengths and weaknesses of JWS. After all not everything you want/need might be possible when using JWS.

Here's a good place to start reading: 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html

Otherwise there are a number of good resources available on JNLP syntax and example code at Sun's Java tutorials, here's the article on [Deployment](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/index.html).